# No component factory found for 'CreatePrefixComponent'

Tags: angular, popup, angular-material, angular6, angular-module

I added a sub component (CreatePrefixComponent) for showing up a popup modal on button click. I got the following error:

```
Error: No component factory found for CreatePrefixComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

But I have added the CreatePrefixComponent in the module of the subcomponent, like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../material.module';
import { PrefixComponent } from './prefix.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { prefixRoutes } from './prefix.routing';
import { CreatePrefixComponent } from './create-prefix/create-prefix.component';
import { MatPaginatorModule, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(prefixRoutes),
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
  ],
  declarations: [PrefixComponent, CreatePrefixComponent],
  entryComponents: [CreatePrefixComponent]
})
export class PrefixModule { }
```

I have use angular material in the project.

Can anybody point me to the right direction, here? Am I missing something ?

Comment: post the `CreatePrefixComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add MatDialogModule and check once..

Comment: Thanks a lot. My mistake was that I didnt include MatDialogModule in the material.module import. Once done it was fixed